# UWP ProgressBar not fully updating from a For loop

Tags: c#, uwp

I am trying to update a ProgressBar from a For loop, in my head, should be easy but I'm struggling a bit.

I've got a Dispatcher method which only seems to fire off twice. Once after the first loop, then not until it has completed. I.e. the loop count should be 6, so each increment would be 16.666667. The ProgressBar will update once to 16.666667 then will wait until the loop has complete to reach 100.

I've read through a few different questions on here, but can't find the answer. I'm still relatively new to this, so any help explained in the dumbest way possible would be appreciated :)

```
double progressIncrease = (double)100 / TodaysFixtures.Count;
ProcessingBar.Value = 0;
for (int fixture = 0; fixture < TodaysFixtures.Count; fixture++)
{
    // ...
    await UpdateProcessingBarAsync(progressIncrease);
}
```

```
private async Task UpdateProcessingBarAsync(double progressIncrease)
{
    await Window.Current.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
    {
        ProcessingBar.Value += progressIncrease;
    });
}
```

Comment: How did you calculate `progressIncrease` inside a loop? If you lalready increased it inside loop, you won't need to increase it inside `RunAsync` call here `ProcessingBar.Value += progressIncrease;`, just set the `progressIncrease`

Comment: try adding some delay: `await Task.Delay(400);` in the loop

Comment: This may be a misunderstanding. From your code, the `ProgressBar.Value` will be superimposed each time. When the `ProgressBar.Value` changes, it has a built-in animation effect, but if the loop is too fast (such as a simple For loop that does not contain any asynchronous delay operations), the human eye cannot recognize it. So you can try using a delay operation like `Task.Delay (500);` in a For loop, so you can see the effect. (P.S. Don't forget to set `ProgressBar.Maximum`)

Comment: @RichardZhang-MSFT hi, I made a custom progressbar so that the animation thing doesn't happen, but it's still same. I would use the `Task.Delay(1)` solution, but it makes the whole loop crazy slow. My work around was to make sure that the `Progressbar.Value` gets updated the least amount of time - like 10 or 11 times. Then the use of `Task.Delay` becomes justified.